# How can I optimize this SQL query in Postgres?

Tags: sql, performance, postgresql, optimization

I've got a pretty large table with nearly 1 million rows and some of the queries are taking a *long* time (over a minute).

Here is one that's giving me a particularly hard time...

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT "apps".* FROM "apps" WHERE "apps"."kind" = 'software' ORDER BY itunes_release_date DESC, rating_count DESC LIMIT 12;
                                                           QUERY PLAN                                                            
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=153823.03..153823.03 rows=12 width=2091) (actual time=162681.166..162681.194 rows=12 loops=1)
   ->  Sort  (cost=153823.03..154234.66 rows=823260 width=2091) (actual time=162681.159..162681.169 rows=12 loops=1)
         Sort Key: itunes_release_date, rating_count
         Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 48kB
         ->  Seq Scan on apps  (cost=0.00..150048.41 rows=823260 width=2091) (actual time=0.718..161561.149 rows=808554 loops=1)
               Filter: (kind = 'software'::text)
 Total runtime: 162682.143 ms
(7 rows)
```

So, how would I optimize that? PG version is 9.2.4, FWIW.

There are already indexes on `kind` and `kind, itunes_release_date`.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but if you have 1 million records, you probably better create an `app_kind` table with numeric references from `apps`, rather than repeating `varchars` such as `'software'` all over

Comment: @LukasEder: or he could use an enum, to keep existing queries untouched.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you're missing an index, e.g. on `(kind, itunes_release_date desc, rating_count desc)`.

Comment: Would an index on `kind` may be enough? Not sure how much the additional columns will speed up the sort.

Comment: An index on kind can be useful but will still yield a top-n sort. To make use of an index to get the top-12 directly, OP will need to add (all of) the sort columns in the index too.

Comment: @AngerClown: The plan seems to indicate that 150k rows have `kind = 'software'`, so the index doesn't filter too selectively

Comment: @LukasEder It can still help as a part of a composite index.

Comment: @LukasEder The index will help to retrieve the limited rows, without sorting the whole table (or the whole 150k rows).

Comment: Thanks guys, I get it ;-) I just wanted to indicate that a single index on `kind` won't do the trick yet, which is why I directed my comment at AngerClown who claimed it would be enough...

Answer (score 0):

How big is the `apps` table? Do you have at least this much memory allocated to postgres? If it's having to read from disk every time, query speed will be much slower.

Another thing that may help is to cluster the table on the 'apps' column. This may speed up disk access since all the `software` rows will be stored sequentially on disk.

Comment: Clustering wont help as the query requires full scan and sort. Postgres memory allocation can help, but not much.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to speed up this query is to create a composite index on `(itunes_release_date, rating_count)`. It will allow Postgres to pick first N rows from the index directly.